# Problems with IDE when requiring permission

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions

After refactoring permission check in a method, so I don't repeat my self, the IDE brings an error. That's reasonable because Android studio can't be sure if I'm asking for permission or just do some if(true) trick.

Question: Does the `@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")` solve the case? Should I do it? Or should I just repeat myself in these situations?

[image]

And the `locationPermissionNotGranted()` is here:

```
fun locationPermissionNotGranted(context: Context) = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, 
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, 
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")` as IDE is unable to track the permission detail.

There is other way too. You simply put a try catch for security exception such as

```
try {
    //permission related stuff
} catch(SecurityException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(e);
}
```